# Pass sub generic type to function need base generic type not working

Tags: vb.net, class, generics

I try to pass a generic type to sub , but get error.

I constraint with base class then pass son class and not working ,am I misunderstood?

Main:

```
Private Sub GenericTypeTest_Load
    Dim tA As New TypeA
    Dim tCon As New TypeContainer(of TypeA)
    subTest(tCon)    'error here
End Sub
```

Class:

```
Public Class TypeBase
End Class

Public Class TypeA : Inherits TypeBase
End Class

Public Class TypeContainer(of T As {TypeBase, New})
End Class
```

Error message :

> Type TypeContainer(Of TypeA) cannot convert to TypeContainer(Of TypeBase)

Oh ,thank for your help and sorry for my bad English and phone typesetting.

Comment: Depending on the details of what you are doing in `subTest`, you may be able to use a covariant interface.  Look up the `Out` keyword in the online Visual Basic help.  Also, think about whether `subTest` needs to take a parameter of `TypeContainer`, or whether it might be able to take `IEnumerable(Of TypeBase)` instead; if the latter,  `IEnumerable(Of T)` is already covariant in `T`.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `TypeA` inherits `TypeBase` does not mean that `TypeContainer(Of TypeA)` inherits `TypeContainer(Of TypeBase)`.  You can only pass an argument to `subTest` that is, inherits or implements the type of the parameter.

Show the declaration of `subTest` and maybe I can be more specific.